# How to redirect a request into another server with virtual directory specifc?

Tags: fiddler

i want to redirect a request from one server into another server using fiddler custom rule 
for example 
if my request contains 
http://server1/virdir1
then it should redirect 
http://server2/virdir2

please help me thanks in advance

EDIT

i have tried this

if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.bayden.com")) { oSession.hostname="test.bayden.com"; }

it works only upto host name

Comment: i have tried this  if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.bayden.com")) {
      oSession.hostname="test.bayden.com";
    } it works only upto host name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("server1") && oSession.uriContains("virdir1") )
{
 oSession.hostname="server2";  
}
```